# Using web worker for api calls

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, web-worker

I'm trying to figure out a clean way for using web workers in order to perform api calls, so far I have this going in client side:

worker-client.js

```
export const workerFetch = (method = "get", url = "/", data = {}) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const listener = `worker_fetch_${url}_${new Date()}`;
    window.lootWorker.postMessage({
      cmd: "worker_fetch",
      payload: { method, url, data, listener }
    });
    window.addEventListener(
      "message",
      ({ data }) => {
        if (data.cmd === listener) {
          if (data.success) resolve(data.data);
          else reject(data.data);
        }
      },
      false
    );
  });
```

so this function can be called from the client and given some parameters.
inside web worker itself

worker-thread.js

```
const workerFetch = ({ method = "get", url = "", data = {}, listener = "" }) => {
  fetch({ method, url, data })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      self.postMessage({ cmd: `worker_fetch_${listener}`, success: true, data });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      self.postMessage({ cmd: `worker_fetch_${listener}`, success: false, data: error });
    });
};

self.addEventListener(
  "message",
  ({ data }) => {
    switch (data.cmd) {
      case "worker_fetch":
        workerFetch(data.payload);
        break;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  },
  false
);
```

In theory this works, but I am concerned about bubbling up those event listeneres in client side, hence this question to see if there is a common way of achieving this functionality that focuses on performance? As after all we are doing this to offload some things from the main thread.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd have a few reservations about this pattern:

1. Remember that only the processing of the *response* is happening on another thread so you'd need to be sure processing your payload is a bottleneck before offloading all fetch requests.
2. If you are concerned about bubbling, you should set `useCapture` in `addEventListener` to `true` and use `stopPropagation` to prevent bubbling to children
3. You are assuming that all fetch calls return in sequence. Now that you're offloading to a worker this can no longer be guaranteed. So you'd need to tag each request with some sort of identifier.

How you implement #3 would be up for debate. If you are focusing on performance, you might want to research some performance UUID generators.

And finally, there appears to be a npm package achieving this functionality: [fetch-worker](https://github.com/marborkowski/fetch-worker)

Comment: This is a useful and accepted answer - not sure why there's no upvoting from over 140 views

Comment: For tracking kind of API calls, we don't need to handle response. Then it would be very useful to handoff load